# Scroll to top from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call jquery to jump to top from iframe.

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  window.parent.$("body,html").animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
 });
 </script>
```

Doesn't work..

//On same domain...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `iframe` is in the same domain as parent then try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("body,html", window.parent).animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
});
```

`window.parent.$("body,html")` will use `window.parent.$` jQuery object but will still look for element inside `iframe` because you are not specifying the context here.

Comment: I have iframe with 11150px height and in Iframe I want to scroll to top of parent if content of iframe changes.

Comment: How does the iframe content changes? Is the iframe refreshed? Or through any ajax calls?

Comment: If you are executing the code in my answer inside the `iframe` it should scroll to the top on page load.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because it's restriction of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). This is not possible if you're on same domain.

If it's on same domain, try to change

```
window.parent.$("body,html")
```

to

```
$("body,html", window.top)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know in JQuery but in simply JS here worked with this:

```
parent.scroll(0, 0)
```

Comment: Doesn´t work ... Btw. FireBug writes an error: Permission denied to access property 'scroll'

Answer (score 1):

To load to top iframe in main page you should
write your javascript function.

```
function loadToTop() {
    parent.self.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

It worked!
Let's enjoy